# Extract command line arguments for a process in kernel using sysctlbyname

Tags: c, macos, kernel, command-line-arguments

I have a requirement to print/log the command line arguments used to start a process (something in line with the `ps` command). The platform is macOS.

For example, if `TestProcess` was started with `-l 10 -m 12`, I should be able to print `TestProcess -l 10 -m 12` into the log.
macOS doesn't provide any direct API for retrieving the command line arguments.

It is possible to get the information using `sysctl()` but this API is not available in kernel. The only API available is `sysctlbyname`. 
I tried `sysctlbyname` but it doesn't give any information.

```
char *proc_n = NULL;
char *funcargs = "kern.procargs2.1122" ; // 1122 is the process id
sysctlbyname(funargs, NULL, &maxsize, NULL, 0);
proc_n = (char*)malloc(maxsize);
sysctlbyname(funargs, proc_n, &maxsize, NULL, 0);
```

`proc_n` is always NULL.

When I pass `kern.procargs2` only, I get some value in proc_n. But it is of no use.

I suspect that there is a different way to pass the process ID. I googled a lot, but was of no help.

Is there any way to pass the process ID to `sysctlbyname`?

Or is there any better way to get the command line arguments for a process in kernel?

Comment: I don't know Mac OS, but is there any /proc/`pid`/cmdline available for each process ID on Mac?

Comment: No, there is no such facility available.

Comment: what's wrong with using sysctl(), again? https://github.com/time-killer-games/xproc run build64.sh to build my example then run `./xproc --pid-enum | xargs -L1 ./xproc --cmd-from-pid` to view all accessible cmdline's running on your machine.